# How to close rmi client safely?

Tags: java, rmi

I want to close all connections between client and server with RMI protocol.

```
   Remote r=  Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.105.38:9121/AccountRMIService");
   if(r instanceof RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub) {
       RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub stub = (RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub)r;
       System.out.println("hashCode="+stub.getRef().hashCode());
   }
   System.out.println(r);
   //How to close the connection with 'Remote' ?
```

Some code to check rmi status of server:

```
final ThreadLocal<List<Socket>> currentSocket = new ThreadLocal<List<Socket>>() {

    protected List<Socket> initialValue() {
        return new ArrayList<Socket>();
    }
};
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new RMISocketFactory() {

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(300);
        currentSocket.get().add(socket);
        return socket;
    }

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        return new ServerSocket(port);
    }
});
Remote r = Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.105.38:9121/AccountRMIService");
if (r instanceof RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub) {
    RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub stub = (RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub) r;
    System.out.println("hashCode=" + stub.getRef().hashCode());
}
Iterator<Socket> s = currentSocket.get().iterator();
while(s.hasNext()) {
    s.next().close();
    s.remove();
}
```

This is not a client for rmi comunication. I just want to check server status using RMI protocol not with simple socket.
Sometimes, the server is still running, but all requests blocked.

Answer (score 2):

You can't 'close all connections' because you have zero visibility of the underlying TCP mechanism. The best you can do in the client is allow all the RMI stubs to be garbage collected. The underlying connections are pooled and closed fairly aggressively anyway.

Answer (score -1):

`UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(Remote obj, boolean force)` can help.

Comment: How to close all connections from client? The server is still running.

Comment: That won't close anything, except maybe a listening socket at the server side, but it will prevent all future clients from performing remote method calls. Not what was asked for.

Answer (score -1):

Try unbind(String name)
Removes the binding for the specified name in this registry.[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html)

Comment: That would be done by a server, not a client, and it doesn't close anything.