# Close RMI connection safely

Tags: java, rmi

how can I close a RMI connection safely and accurately..

For example close the connection of the RMI below..

Thanks

```
   try {           
        Remote kay = Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/hey");
        Hey u = (Hey) kay;  
        u.canSaw(que);              
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8815342/1743880

Answer (score 0):

It's better to leave it - the connection between RMI client and server is implicit. The connection closes after a short idle period of time automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I close a RMI connection safely and accurately.

There is no such thing as an RMI connection, *ergo* there is nothing to close, either safely or accurately.

RMI's TCP connections are managed invisibly under the hood. There are some system properties to control them, defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html).

Just let the *stub* be garbage-collected.